# SL.cpp: In member function ‘int sll::search()’: SL.cpp:122:15: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
int sll:: search(){
    node *p;
    int f=0,k;
    p=head;
    cout<<"Enter the element you want to found";
    cin>>k;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {

        if(p->next == k)
        {
            f=1;
            cout<<"Element found";
        }
        else
        {
            p=p->next;
        }}
    if(f==0)
    {
        cout<<"Element not found";
    }
    return(0);
}
```

> SL.cpp: In member function ‘int sll::search()’:
>   SL.cpp:122:15: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
>    if(p->next == k)

Comment: Seems pretty clear that `p->next` is a pointer an `k` is an integer. If you showed how `node` is declared it could be helpful.

Comment: `if (p->next == k)` `p->next` is a pointer, `k` is an integer. What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: You should be using `if (p->data == k)`. Replace `data` with the actual name of the member that contains the value of the node.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i need to found search element in the code            class sll
{
struct list
{
int data;
struct list *next;
}*head;
public:
typedef struct list node;
sll();
void search();
};
sll::sll()
{
head=NULL;
}

Comment: @Barmar  i need to found search element in the code class sll { struct list { int data; struct list *next; }*head; public: typedef struct list node; sll(); void search(); }; sll::sll() { head=NULL; }

Comment: So what's the problem? Doesn't `if (p->data == k)` work?